# Calculating average of distinct column values in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following excel sheet

```
  C                D                E


Activity1         40%     Sub activity
Activity1         30%     Sub activity
Activity2         20%     Sub activity
Activity2         20%     Sub activity
Activity2         70%     Sub activity
Activity3         30%     Sub activity
Activity3         30%     Sub activity
Activity3         30%     Sub activity
```

I want to get an output like this

```
           A             B
      Activity1         35%
      Activity2         30%
      Activity3         30%
```

I am new to excel please help me on how to get the result like that?
which formula can i use to get something like this??

Comment: something like this: `=AVERAGEIF(C1:C10,"Activity1",D1:D10)` for calculating average

Comment: @Kabir Can i get that average % completed too??

Comment: `@Vighnesh` Seems a problem though, what is the logic of getting Activity2 value as 30% ,it should be 36.666% approx to 37%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do something like this:

Select the data , Hit  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and three times <kbd>enter</kbd>.You got a pivot table in new sheet.

In values take average instead of sum , If the format is not in percentage , Hit  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+  <kbd>5</kbd>  , you have the numbers in percentage format now.

[image]

[image]

I hope this would help